# What is the best type of server to use for Android?

Tags: android

I am creating an app which saves notes and would like to have it able to sync with a PC desktop application. The thing I'm wondering is what type of server is best to use and how I would save and retrieve data from the server?

All the data will be strings or an Array of strings.

Comment: That depends what your server will do with your data. 
If your are planing to create web application, next question is what programming language you will use (php, ruby, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a RESTful application you have several possibilities. I recommend you to take a look at several PaaS. The main advantage of using a PaaS is that you can use Tomcat as a Service, Jetty as a Service, Glassfish as a Service, what means that you don't have to manage the server as you just need to deploy your application as they take care of the stack.

These PaaS usually offer MySQL, Mongo or PostgrSQL databases. You could try before paying as they usually offer a free tier in which you can test everything.

There are several that you can try:

- [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/). This one also cover the development process offering
  Jenkins as a Service, which is usually really important, specially if several developers are working on the same project. You can also build Android or iOS applications. Also, you have the possibility to use an emulator for the cloud so as to test that everything works fine before deploying your application to the server for the production environment.
- GAE
- Amazon Beanstalk
- ...

Answer (score 1):

I used the Glassfish server and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will "speak" with RESTful Webservices and transport JSON Objects.

Now it depends on your programming skills.

If you choose PHP, you will find thousands of hosters where you can put the server code.

Take Tomcat/GlassFish/... if you master Java.

I personally prefer node.js (with express and MongoDB). The big advantage is that you don't have so many different representations of data. Just JSON - no conversion necessary and the objects are natively embedded in the language (JavaScript) and in the database.

On Android side you have to call the REST-services with HttpUrlConnection or AndroidHttpClient (not recommended for Android >= 2.3).

Of course there are many more options (Ruby on Rails, Python, .NET)

If you want to go online someday (not only Desktop), take into account the hosting services and prices for hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google App Engine its easy to setup, hosted on google environment. Which might fulfill your need. In this case you don't need to buy hosting plans etc. etc. You will get yourappname.appspot.com URL to use app server.

- Appengine supports Python and Java.

hope this helps you